# Complexity of pixel detection in quantum images

Tags: grovers-algorithm

In this paper [Identification of Desired Pixels in an Image Using Grover's Quantum Search
Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.03053.pdf)
 it is stated in the abstract that "[...]As has been observed in complexity
analysis, Grover's unstructured search has the $O(2^n)$ while as for classical schemes
$O(2^{2n+2m})$, where $m$ and $n$ denote the dimensions of the image."

Their goal is to apply Grover's algorithm in order to find the desired pixel (darkest ones below certain threshold). This could be useful for detecting data hiding in steganography.They use NEQR for image encoding.

What I don't undestand is the complexity $O$ for the classical scheme. Why is it $2^{2n+2m}$ against $2^{n}$ in the quantum case?

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
Here is the circuit for the following list of elements (it is not the implementation of a grayscale image, is just a reduced example): according to NEQR notation, the first two qubits represent the index of four elements, i.e. 00, 01, 10 and 11, whilst the others the encoding of the value, in this case 1,2,5 and 7 {00001,01010,10101,11111}. The threshold is all numbers less than 5, that is the oracle marks the numbers 00001 and 01010. The diffuser is the standard one that can be found anywhere on the web. Of course in the case of four pixel of a grayscale images we would need 8 (for intensity) + 2 (for position) qubits.

[Quirk circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%7Ejom5%22%5D,%5B%22%7E5l72%22%5D,%5B%22%7Ejom5%22%5D,%5B%22%7E5l72%22%5D,%5B%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D%5D,%22gates%22:%5B%7B%22id%22:%22%7En9ca%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22%5D%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22%7Ejom5%22,%22name%22:%22Pf%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22%5D%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22%7E40tr%22,%22name%22:%22Pf%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22%5D%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22%7E5l72%22,%22name%22:%22D%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D) ([simplified](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22NeGate%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22NeGate%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22NeGate%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22NeGate%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22NeGate%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22NeGate%22%5D%2C%5B%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance2%22%5D%5D%7D))

I don't understand how to read Quirk measurements, if I run the circuit on Qiskit I get the following results: {'11': 20, '00': 468, '10': 487, '01': 25} over 1000 shots, that is '00' and '10' are the position of the elements below my threshold, so I think it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Their claim that the processing time is $2^n$ instead of $2^{2n} \times 2^{2m}$ for an $n \times m$ image is simply wrong. (A red flag is how it isn't justified or cited, just stated with an appeal to "as has been observed in complexity analysis".)

The correct numbers would be $O(\sqrt{nm})$ quantum pixel queries vs $O(nm)$ classical pixel queries. Also, keep in mind that if the image starts as classical data, then the quantum cost includes $O(nm)$ classical pixel queries to prepare the representation.

Also, I'm pretty sure you can't just apply Grover's algorithm to the "NEQR" representation they describe and have it do the right thing. I'm very skeptical of the results they show for that, but I can't tell you for sure because they don't actually specify exactly the circuit they are running or provide source code.

In my experience, this kind of sloppiness is typical of papers with "quantum image processing" in the title. I've just stopped reading them; they're consistently a waste of time. There is a similar thing that happens in cryptography: ["image encryption" isn't fundamentally different from just encryption, so a paper *focusing* on "image encryption" is strong signal that it's bad](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87274/7860).

For actually cool image processing results, you go to places that focus on image/video processing such as SIGGRAPH. Actually, SIGGRAPH is the only place where I saw a quantum image processing paper I liked: ["Quantum Supersampling"](https://history.siggraph.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/2016-Talks-Johnston_Quantum-Supersampling.pdf) by Eric R. Johnston. In their [talk](https://vimeo.com/180284417) they even demonstrate a clear understanding of how costly this would be, placing it in far-future quantum-computers-are-cheap land.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Craig! I had some doubts too about the complexity being wrong. As for the application of Grover's algorithm, I think it can be possible to apply it to the NEQR representation, as the image is just being encoded in $n$ qubits of the circuit, thus applying the oracle and the diffuse on those states can give you the answer one is looking for. I will have a look at the paper you linked!

Comment: @aghin00 Grover's algorithm requires your initial state to match the diffusion step that you are doing. A NEQR state would require a NEQR diffuser, which would be more complex than the usual one in a way that would likely defeat the speedup. The paper never talks abut this, which is the source of my suspicion.

Comment: I've tried their implementation, by putting all qubits needed for the representation of the image in superposition (NEQR required only the index qubits to be in superposition), like they did in their last figure, and then applied the oracle and the general diffuser on all qubits. Actually, the results I've got seems pretty good: I used only 5 qubits for the sake of example, and I wanted to get two states that were below a certain threshold implemented by the oracle. Over all 4 possible states, I get the desired two with equal and high probability with respect to the others. I don't know

Comment: @aghin00 Can you put your circuit into quirk https://algassert.com/quirk and link it in your question? I want to see it working.

Comment: I edited the question with the quirk circuit. As I mention there, I don't know to use quirk so it was just for a bettere explanation. I actually use Qiskit and I get the results I mentioned. I'm waiting for you to come back at it!

Comment: @aghin00 I simplified the circuit for you. But note that (a) the results of the circuit don't agree with what they have in the paper (they say it returns 3 results with p~=1/3 whereas you're getting 2 with p~=1/2) and (b) deleting the CNOT gates at the start of the circuit doesn't change the answer, so the answer is failing to depend on the "brightness"!

Comment: Regarding (a), the fact that they get three answers with that p is due to their building of the example. If I build mine with a threshold of 7 (11111) I’m pretty sure I will get the numbers of answers accordingly (of course the oracle will have to change). Could you elaborate more point (b)? The CNOT at the beginning serves for the NEQR representation (again, note that I’m not representing pixels in my example, just numbers following the NEQR way). What do you mean by “failing to depend on the brigthness”?

Comment: @aghin00 The CNOTs at the beginning are preparing the brightness. The circuit is supposed to tell you the bright pixels. If it gives the same answer when you delete the CNOTs, it is clearly not telling you something about the brightness. Because the CNOTs *are* the brightness.

Comment: what could be the problem regarding the CNOTs? I mean, if the first part of the circuit is supposed to encode the states in the NEQR states, the CNOTs are needed. So why does the circuit give the same answer even if we get rid of them? This would mean that their paper is not just wrong, but completely wrong..

Comment: @aghin00 Well, keep in mind they don't report the same answer you're getting so they're probably using a different circuit. My suspicion is that they are either putting the image encoder/decoder into the oracle (defeating the cost benefit) or just making a mistake where they made a circuit that returns the correct states by accident. But I can't tell which, or if I'm mistaken, because they don't provide the circuit they ran.

Comment: you're right... However, I played a bit with the circuit and I found something: instead of putting all the qubits in superposition with H gates at the beginning, I applied H just on the first two (the ones for indexing); then I put the encoding of the values in NEQR representation, with CNOTs; the oracle is the same, applied on all qubits in order to mark the ones below the threshold; the diffuser, instead, is now applied only on the first two qubits (we want to amplify the indexes who match what we want). The iterations are still two [continue]

Comment: [continue] If I do this I get something like {'11': 344, '00': 124, '01': 394, '10': 138}, and if I get rid of the CNOTs, now the results are not the same: {'01': 265, '10': 241, '11': 261, '00': 233}. Could this be the right way on telling something about the brightness?

Comment: @aghin00 That version of the circuit is the one I was referring to when I said it included the encoder/decoder oracle. The issue is this version of the circuit doesn't make sense for the "image processing" use case. The image is supposed to be given as data, not as an oracle. Implementing it as an oracle destroys all the cost benefits.